# Import functions in a script with parameters

Tags: powershell

I have a script with parameters:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$VaultName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$SecretName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][bool]$AddToMono = $false
 )
...
```

In this script I want to include functions that I wrote in another ps1 file : common.ps1

I usually import this with

```
. .\common.ps1
```

but if I do that in the script I get:

```
The term '.\common.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
```

How do I import common.ps1 in this script?

Thanks!

Comment: Give the full path of the common.ps1 in the dot source

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are running the script from a different directory.  PowerShell is looking for `.\common.ps1` using the *current directory*, not the directory of the script.  To get around this, use the built-in variable `$PSScriptRoot`, which contains the path of the current script.  (I'm assuming you are using PowerShell v3.0 or later.)

## common.ps1

```
function foo {
    return "from foo"
}
```

## with_params.ps1

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$VaultName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$SecretName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][bool]$AddToMono = $false
 )

 . $PSScriptRoot\common.ps1

 Write-Output "Vault name is $VaultName"
 foo
```

I then executed this:

```
 PS> .\some_other_folder\with_params.ps1 -VaultName myVault -SecretName secretName -AddToMono $false
```

and got this output:

```
Vault name is myVault
from foo
```